# Real time database with Storage in Firebase in Android

Tags: firebase-storage, real-time-data

Any ideas on combining storage e.g pictures, or videos with real time database? meaning, am looking for solution where by admin can save image and some details on the storage in firebase, and users can comment on the image or video using real time database? how is it achievable? e.g. same thing like instagram

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792870/android-firebase-storage-image-retrieval-associated-with-database-object

Comment: I have asked a question 2 days back, you put yesterday link instead...lol @MikeMcDonald

Comment: Heh, though people answered the other one, so I might as well use that answer.