# Android Firebase Storage Image Retrieval associated with Database Object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am currently storing an Object in a Firebase Database containing name, description and base64 of a photo. I know this is not a good practice but it works for now. I have some knowledge how to upload to a firebase storage and how to retrieve an image. Let's say I want to upload an object do a database containing name and description and also a photo but this time to the storage. And let's say there is 100 of those objects with 100 images. What should I do that each object is associated with the correct image?

Comment: Giving them the same name/path is a common way of associating images with database nodes.

Comment: But there are two different paths for database nodes and for storage images. How is that possible?

Comment: It's just a convention: if you use the same path structure for both, you can associate them with each other. A path `/users/martynaskuc/data` in the database and `/users/martynaskuc/photos` in storage can then both be yours and be secured based on your UID ([storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security), [database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security)).

Comment: Does It mean I have to get them the same Key that is generated for DB object? By the way- is there any documentation or Code Samples for that?

Comment: Yes: Zero to App (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE&t=141s, Android source: https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c) discusses how to do this

Comment: Thanks it is pretty much the as same as Friendly Chat App on udacity. But What If I want to send a message AND a Picture in one go? How would that be handled? For Example - I send a picture of an apple and write "apple" and they both appear as a single message.

Comment: What I am looking for is some sort of connection/association between Database objects and Storage files.  Let's say there are three database objects DB1, DB2, DB3 and three storage files S1, S2, S3. And whenever I choose DB1 I get to see S1, when I choose DB2 I get to see S2 and so on. I was thinking also of putting a Storage download URL as a database field but I am not sure about that yet